# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable - Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi guys i'm making a Temperature Converter based on Tkinter in Python and it was all good but now i'm getting this error. I looked here on stackoverflow for this error, i found a lot of them but i couldn't figured out, so i'm here to post my code to see if you guys can help. The program crashes exactly when i click a option on the OptionMenu. (om_input specifically)

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

It throws another exception:

```
AttributeError: 'StringVar' object has no attribute '_report_exception'
```

Here are snippets of my code:

> This function is supposed to be called everytime the user selects an option in the OptionMenu in the GUI.

```
def check_entry():

if temperature_input.get() == "Celsius":
    celsius_converter(value_entry.get(), temperature_output.get(), output_entry)

elif temperature_input.get() == "Kelvin":
    kelvin_converter(value_entry.get(), temperature_output.get(), output_entry)

else:
    fahrenheit_converter(value_entry.get(), temperature_output.get(), output_entry)
```

> The vars to be used with the OptionMenus

```
root = Tk()
temperature_list = ["Celsius", "Kelvin", "Fahrenheit"]    

temperature_input = StringVar(root)
temperature_input.set(temperature_list[0])

temperature_output = StringVar(root)
temperature_output.set(temperature_list[0])

output_entry = Entry(root, state=NORMAL)
```

> Initialization of the OptionMenus

```
om_input = OptionMenu(root, temperature_input, *temperature_list, command=check_entry)
om_output = OptionMenu(root, temperature_output, *temperature_list, command=check_entry)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: please provide a complete working program with the smallest amount of code that reproduces the problem (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Is that your entire traceback? I'd expect to see lines like `File "myfile.py", line 9` and such before the actual error message. Did you cut anything out?

Comment: Well, while i was working on a minimal program, the program seemed to work, now i'm looking for whats different but i don't think anything is. I cut the parts i didn't think it was important for the problem.

Comment: I solved it. Just changed some things in a method. I'm new here, sorry for not posting correctly. Thanks for your time guys.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it and the problem was in a method that i didn't post here, stupidly, and i apologize for that.

The method was like that:

```
def update_entry():
    temp_input.trace("w", check_entry())
    root.after(1, update_entry)
```

I went through Tkinter documentations and read about StringVar and the trace() method and i just changed "w" to "u", worked charmly. Thanks for your time.